# Tool for path finding algorithm testing

Tags: algorithm, testing, path

Anyone know, some tool for path finding algorithm testing.
Where i could test my own writed path finding algorithm on 2d grid.
Something like this http://topfat.blogspot.com/
But where i could write and run my own algorithms.
It could be using any programming language.
I can adjust my code almost to any programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the source code for Tool for Path Finding algorithm? I'm one of the developers and the tool is open source (Java). For example the interface that your algorithm should implement is

```
public interface PathFindingAlgorithm {

    /**
     * Method for finding path from given start point to goal point
     * using Map object. Found path (if any) depends on path finding algorithm
     * class that overrides this method.
     * 
     * @param start the point where the search begins
     * @param goal the goal point
     * @param map Map object the path finding algorithm uses
     * @return SearchResult object containing path and possibly other relevant information
     * about the search and <code>null</code> if no path is found.
     */
    public SearchResult findPath(Point start, Point goal, Graph graph);
```

Class where you add your algorithm (http://code.google.com/p/topfat/source/browse/trunk/src/algorithms/PathFindingAlgorithms.java):

```
public class PathFindingAlgorithms {

    private Vector<PathFindingAlgorithm> algorithms;

    public PathFindingAlgorithms() {
            this.algorithms = new Vector<PathFindingAlgorithm>();
            addAlgorithm(new AStarAlgorithm());
            addAlgorithm(new DijkstraStyleAlgorithm());
    }

    public Vector<PathFindingAlgorithm> getAlgorithms() {
            return algorithms;
    }

    public void addAlgorithm(PathFindingAlgorithm algorithm) {

            if (! this.algorithms.contains(algorithm)) {
                    this.algorithms.add(algorithm);
            }

    }

    public void removeAlgorithm(PathFindingAlgorithm algorithm) {
            this.algorithms.remove(algorithm);
    }
```

I don't remember exactly if this also adds everything needed to the GUI. We did this few years ago so the code is (of course) not perfect. The simplest case in this application is Dijkstra and if you need something more complicated, check A*.

You can do check out from Google Code http://code.google.com/p/topfat/. If you do something you'd like to commit, we can add writing permissions for you too.

Comment: I am studying at university and working at project related with path finding algorithms. I searched for program like that in internet and could not find. So i asked maybe there already is program like that. Now i am just checking aviable options and alternatives.